# iOS - Having 2 table views and other elements under one TableViewController

Tags: ios, uiview, uitableview

I'm trying to make an interface like this one:

[image] [image]

But I get the following error in XCode: `Illegal Configuration: Static table views are only valid when embedded in UITableViewController instances`

That controller is a subclass of UITableViewController, so I don't really understand what the problem is, any insight?

Comment: Alright, any way to get this kind of layout then?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, I think you're saying that ProfileViewController is a subclass of UITableViewController. If that is the case, the top level view should be a UITableView not just a UIView. And the error does make sense. If you want to create a static table view, it needs to be embedded in it's own UITableViewController, which is what you get when you drag a UITableViewController from the Palette to the storyboard.

**Amended** to answer question in comments

So starting from scratch. Drag a TableViewController onto your storyboard and change the class to ProfileViewController. That gives you your tableview with the prototype cells. Then drag an empty view to near the top of the TableView. This will add a headerview to the tableView. (Every tableview has a subview for a header and a footer. This is different than the section headers). Now make that header view taller and drag your other elements into it: the segmentedButton, the search field. Drag your UIImage View. then drag another tableview and position it next to the image view.

Now create a subclass of NSObject NOT NSTableViewController like so.

`@interface MiniTableViewController : NSObject <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>`

And put the datasource and delegate methods for that minitableview in there. Back on the story board, drag an object to the hierarchy change the class to your MiniTableViewController, and connect the delegate and datasource outlets from your minitableview to the MiniTableViewController in the hierarchy. Make sure you're using the assistant view. Then ctrl-drag from the MiniTableViewController object to the ProfileViewController.h (right before @end) and create an IBOutlet. Now you can access your new custom object from ProfileViewController. You can also create an IBOutlet in MiniTableViewController and connect it to ProfileViewController if you need MiniTableViewController to send messages to ProfileViewController.

Comment: Any way I can achieve this kind of layout?

Answer (score 2):

A UITableViewController can only have one Table View.  You have two.  You have to find another way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you put a UITableView in your xib ?
If yes, have you bind this UITableView to your controller?

Comment: All those elements are over a UIView, I'll update with a pick of the hierarchy.

Comment: And this answer should probably have been a comment

Comment: If your class was inherited from UITableViewController, you should to use a tableview as main graphic element. So i suggest you to change your parent class from UITableViewController to UIViewController.